# Manage LXC containers from host in puppet

Tags: puppet, lxc

Is there any puppet modules for manage nodes in LXC containers from local host? E.g.: I have host with 50 LXC containers and I want to manage all those containers from host directly, not from another one LXC container with `puppetmaster`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [existing Puppet module](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/dmexe/lxc), which doesn't seem to be well documented in terms of usage nor features.

You'll be probably more lucky if you're using Docker as a wrapper around plain LXC.

The [Docker Puppet module](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/garethr/docker) seems to have meaningful documentation + [Docker](http://docker.io) itself could help you to manage these containers a bit more effectively in general.